# Regular Expression for a range between

Tags: regex, expression

I checked around but didn't find a regular expression that was suitable. I'm trying to match on only numbers (8-32) and tried a few combinations that were unsuccessful including `(Regex regex = new Regex("[8-9]|[10-29]\\d",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);)`. This only got me up to 8-29 and then I got lost.

I know there is a better and easier way if I just create an if statement, but I'll never learn anything doing it that way. :-)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using ? Why not use a simple if condition ?

Comment: @Paul-Etienne Seems like C#

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah you're right, why do you want to use a regex for that ?

Comment: Your requirement is not suitable for a regex. This could be solved very easily with an if condition.

Comment: The comments above are 100% correct.  `([8-9] | [1-2][0-9] | 3[0-2])` will work, although there are caveats like "29" also including "9"

Comment: Yes, I'm programming in C# but using Sweepers clarification, I'll just simply stick to my condition statement. Thank you so much for the reply all of you. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex for checking whether a number is in a range is a bad idea. Regex only cares about what characters are in the string, not what the value of each character represents. The regex engine doesn't know that `2` in `23` actually means `20`. To it, it's the same as any other `2`.

You might be able to write a highly complex regex to do that, but *don't*.

Assuming you are using C#, just convert the string to an integer like this

```
var integer = Convert.ToInt32(yourString);
```

then check if it is in range with an if statement:

```
if (integer >= 8 && integer <= 32) {

}
```

If your number is a part of a larger string, *then* you can use regex to extract the number out, convert it to an `int`, and check it with an if.

Comment: Thank you for the response Sweeper. I've already did a condition statement, but was thinking I could do an expression. Thanks for the clarification I think I'll just stick with my if statement. :-) Oh, either way yes I'm programming in C#.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference for regex testing with explanations, I would suggest you https://regexr.com/
And for your need : 8-32, you will want a pattern like

[8-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]

So that you will get 8 or 9 or every number between 10 and 29 or 30 to 32